# I am not able to import Keras "from keras.applications import VGG19"and the respective application I want on Colab. Help me as it is important

Tags: python, keras

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.applications import VGG19
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import cv2
```

Please help me to resolve the error which i m getting on colab. I m new to coding section and have very little knowledge about it. Please help me resolve this error ImportError: cannot import name 'VGG19' from 'keras.applications' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/applications/**init**.py).

Comment: instead of `from keras.applications import VGG19` try `from tf.keras.applications import VGG19`

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-873b61798832> in <module>()
      5 import tensorflow
      6 import keras
----> 7 from tf.keras.applications import VGG19
      8 from keras.models import Sequential
      9 from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'
It shows this error now @hypadr1v3 Please help

Comment: what's your version of keras and tensorflow?

Answer (score 2):

the right syntax is

```py
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19
```

You omitted the .vgg19 from your syntax

Answer (score 0):

I made I model with VGG19. Images size for input_shape were 220. And then my model trained 2 diferents images types:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG19

modelVGG19_4 = tf.keras.Sequential()

modelVGG19_4.add(tf.keras.applications.VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
            pooling='avg', input_shape=(220, 220, 3)))

modelVGG19_4.summary()
modelVGG19_4.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax"))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.004)


modelVGG19_4.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

modelVGG19_4.summary()
```